# Create grandchild in Menu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menu, menubar

In my Menu I need to create a submenu in submenu. I need to do this in my MenuBean

below is the image Like I Need:

[image]

below is the exemple of primefaces MenuBean, but does not have what I would like

```
//First submenu
 DefaultSubMenu firstSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Dynamic Submenu");

 DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("External");
 item.setUrl("http://www.primefaces.org");
 item.setIcon("ui-icon-home");
 firstSubmenu.addElement(item);

 model.addElement(firstSubmenu);

 //Second submenu
 DefaultSubMenu secondSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Dynamic Actions");

 item = new DefaultMenuItem("Save");
 item.setIcon("ui-icon-disk");
 item.setCommand("#{menuBean.save}");
 item.setUpdate("messages");
 secondSubmenu.addElement(item);

 item = new DefaultMenuItem("Delete");
 item.setIcon("ui-icon-close");
 item.setCommand("#{menuBean.delete}");
 item.setAjax(false);
 secondSubmenu.addElement(item);

 item = new DefaultMenuItem("Redirect");
 item.setIcon("ui-icon-search");
 item.setCommand("#{menuBean.redirect}");
 secondSubmenu.addElement(item);

 model.addElement(secondSubmenu);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add SubMenus into SubMenus. Following the example you gave us, I made a few arrangement so you can see what I mean:

```
//First submenu
 DefaultSubMenu firstSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Dynamic Submenu");

 DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("External");
 item.setUrl("http://www.primefaces.org");
 item.setIcon("ui-icon-home");
 firstSubmenu.addElement(item);



 //Second submenu
 DefaultSubMenu secondSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Dynamic Actions");

 item = new DefaultMenuItem("Save");
 item.setIcon("ui-icon-disk");
 item.setCommand("#{menuBean.save}");
 item.setUpdate("messages");
 secondSubmenu.addElement(item);

 item = new DefaultMenuItem("Delete");
 item.setIcon("ui-icon-close");
 item.setCommand("#{menuBean.delete}");
 item.setAjax(false);
 secondSubmenu.addElement(item);

 item = new DefaultMenuItem("Redirect");
 item.setIcon("ui-icon-search");
 item.setCommand("#{menuBean.redirect}");

 secondSubmenu.addElement(firstSubmenu); //child inside a child
 secondSubmenu.addElement(item);

 model.addElement(secondSubmenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is example (ManagedBean):

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;  
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;  
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;  

public class MenuBean {  

    public void save(ActionEvent actionEvent) {  
        addMessage("Data saved");  
    }  

    public void update(ActionEvent actionEvent) {  
        addMessage("Data updated");  
    }  

    public void delete(ActionEvent actionEvent) {  
        addMessage("Data deleted");  
    }  

    public void addMessage(String summary) {  
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, summary,  null);  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);  
    }  
}
```

and this for your xhtml page:

```
<h:form>  

    <p:growl id="messages"/>  

    <p:menubar autoSubmenuDisplay="true">  
        <p:submenu label="File" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-document">  
            <p:submenu label="New" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-contact">  
                <p:menuitem value="Project" url="#" helpText="CTRL+N" />  
                <p:menuitem value="Other" url="#" helpText="CTRL+O"/>  
            </p:submenu>  
            <p:menuitem value="Open" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Quit" url="#" />  
        </p:submenu>  

        <p:submenu label="Edit" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil">  
            <p:menuitem value="Undo" url="#" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w" helpText="CTRL+Z"></p:menuitem>  
            <p:menuitem value="Redo" url="#" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-e" helpText="CTRL+Y"></p:menuitem>  
        </p:submenu>  

        <p:submenu label="Help" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-help">  
            <p:menuitem value="Contents" url="#" />  
            <p:submenu label="Search" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search">  
                <p:submenu label="Text">  
                    <p:menuitem value="Workspace" url="#" />  
                </p:submenu>  
                <p:menuitem value="File" url="#" />  
            </p:submenu>  
        </p:submenu>  

        <p:submenu label="Actions" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-gear">  
            <p:submenu label="Ajax" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh">  
                <p:menuitem value="Save" actionListener="#{buttonBean.save}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-disk" update="messages"/>  
                <p:menuitem value="Update" actionListener="#{buttonBean.update}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w" update="messages"/>  
            </p:submenu>  
            <p:submenu label="Non-Ajax" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin">  
                <p:menuitem value="Delete" actionListener="#{buttonBean.delete}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-close" update="messages" ajax="false"/>  
            </p:submenu>  
        </p:submenu>  

        <p:menuitem value="Quit" url="http://www.primefaces.org" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-close" />  
    </p:menubar>  

</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks Hamdi Hasnaoui, but in my xhtm use only: 
<h:form>   
    <p:menubar model="#{menuBean.model}">
</h:form>

as the example of primefaces